# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' - although the information is on the website

Tags: python, error-handling, web-scraping

the code below stops where the error occurs. When accessing the page, the keyword "redzone" is there however, the script doesn't return the results, thus the error in the title.

```
import re
import requests
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print ('<HEAD><TITLE>Buffalo Streams</TITLE></HEAD>')
print ('<body link="#5ba0c1">')
print ('<p />')

try:
   my_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/NFLStreams/'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
   uClient = uReq(my_url)
   page_html = uClient.read()
   uClient.close()

# html parsing
   page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
   linktwo = 'http://www.reddit.com'
   linkone = page_soup.find('a', href=True, text=re.compile(r"\b[Rr]edzone\b"))['href']
```

If I change the `(r"\b[Rr]edzone\b")` to a sports team name, it works. For some odd reason, this text doesn't return anything value. Why?

Comment: Just a quick look at the page... looks like you're after RedZone (note the capital Z)?

Comment: How would I handle the capital Z like I do for the R? Would I add this: `(r"\b[Rr]ed[Zz]one\b")`?

Comment: That's one option or just make the regex case insensitive or whatever...

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: Google "python regex case insensitive".

Comment: If regex is not the only criterion to get the desired output then you can serve the purpose very easily.